# Coq: Notation or Definition on a universe as a variable

Tags: types, coq

Is it possible to define a notation or a definition on a *universe as a variable*? The following

```
Universe x.
Notation "/ x" := Type@{x}.
```

results in the left-side `x` being a variable and the right-side `x` a constant:

```
Check /u. (*Type@{x} : Type@{x+1}*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Set Universe Polymorphism.
Definition in_type@{i} x := (x : Type@{i}).
Check in_type@{Set} nat.
```

Note that the definition must be universe-polymorphic for this to work.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. Interestingly, the same doesn't work w/ notations: `Notation "type@{ i }" := Type@{i}. Fail Check type@{Set}. (*Error: Undeclared universe: i*)` (probably due to transparency, as `Fail Check Type@{i}.` gives the same error)

Comment: The way to do that is `Set Universe Polymorphism. Notation type := Type. Check type@{_}.`  I'm not sure what you mean by transparency.  Note that variables in notations are bound in a completely separate namespace from universes.  You could make a feature request for something like `i universe `, as in, `Notation "type@{ i }" := Type@{i} (i universe).`

Comment: `Set Universe Polymorphism.` was prepended to my example. `Set Universe Polymorphism. Notation type := Type. Check type@{_}.` gives `Syntax error: [constr:universe_level] expected after '@{' (in [instance]).` Substituting the check w/ `Check type@{Set}.` gives `Error: Notation type cannot have a universe instance, its expanded head does not start with a reference`. By "transparency" I meant an "abrupt unfolding" to `Type@{i}`. PS. A definition suffices for me here -- just mentioned that this doesn't work w/ notations. (I'm using Coq 8.6.1)

Comment: Oh, uh, `@{_}` apparently only works in >= 8.7+beta1.  And, oh, huh, I think the error is a bug in Coq.  (Reported as https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5726.)  This works: `Set Universe Polymorphism.
Definition type' := Type.
Notation type := type'.
Check type@{Set}.`

Comment: Feature request for `i universe` at https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=5727